# Weird error " multiple definition of `xxx` " while compiling C++ project

Tags: c++, compilation, header, makefile

When I try to compile my C++ project  via my Makefile I keep getting errors like those:

```
Server.o: In function `Bot::getRandomMessage()':
/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/./Bot.cpp:18: multiple definition of `Bot::getRandomMessage()'
Bot.o:/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/./Bot.cpp:18: first defined here
Server.o: In function `Bot':
/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/./Bot.cpp:27: multiple definition of `Bot::Bot()'
Bot.o:/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/./Bot.cpp:27: first defined here
Server.o: In function `~Bot':
/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/./Bot.cpp:30: multiple definition of `Bot::~Bot()'
Bot.o:/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/./Bot.cpp:30: first defined here
Server.o: In function `~Bot':
/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/./Bot.cpp:30: multiple definition of `Bot::~Bot()'
Bot.o:/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/./Bot.cpp:30: first defined here
Server.o: In function `~Bot':
/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/./Bot.cpp:30: multiple definition of `Bot::~Bot()'
Bot.o:/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/./Bot.cpp:30: first defined here
Server.o: In function `Bot::getName()':
/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/./Bot.cpp:33: multiple definition of `Bot::getName()'
Bot.o:/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/./Bot.cpp:33: first defined here
Server.o: In function `ChatRoom::getCurrentTime()':
/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/./Server.cpp:74: multiple definition of `ChatRoom::getCurrentTime()'
main.o:/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/./Server.cpp:74: first defined here
Server.o: In function `Bot::getRandomMessage()':
/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/./Bot.cpp:18: multiple definition of `vectorOfThreads'
main.o:/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/./Server.cpp:74: first defined here
Server.o: In function `Bot::getRandomMessage()':
```

I'm quite confused with that.. When I compile it directly with the command 
`g++ main.cpp -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb -lncurses -pthread -o AppName` , then it doesn't produce any error. So I expect, that the error appears somewhere in my `Makefile`

```
#macros
Remove=rm -rf
Doxygen=Doxyfile
RUN=./dvoram64
FLAGS=-Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb -pthread -lncurses -g
OBJECTS=main.o Bot.o Server.o Client.o GrumpyBot.o JokerBot.o WeatherBot.o DummyBot.o

#generates final binary and documentation
all:    $(Doxygen)
    make compile

#build into final binary
compile: $(RUN)

#run program
run:    
    make link
    $(RUN)
    $(RUN)


clean:
    $(Remove) dvoram64
    $(Remove) $(OBJECTS)

#generate documentation in '<login>/doc' folder
doc: $(Doxygen) /*
    ( cd ./ | doxygen $(Doxygen))

link: $(OBJECTS)
    g++ $(OBJECTS) -lncurses -pthread -o dvoram64

#rules how to compile into the executalble file
$(RUN): $(OBJECTS)

Bot.o: ./Bot.cpp ./Bot.h
    g++ $(FLAGS) -c ./Bot.cpp

DummyBot.o: ./DummyBot.cpp ./DummyBot.h ./Bot.h
    g++ $(FLAGS) -c ./DummyBot.cpp

GrumpyBot.o: ./GrumpyBot.cpp ./GrumpyBot.h ./Bot.h
    g++ $(FLAGS) -c ./GrumpyBot.cpp

JokerBot.o: ./JokerBot.cpp ./JokerBot.h ./Bot.h
    g++ $(FLAGS) -c ./JokerBot.cpp

WeatherBot.o: ./WeatherBot.cpp ./WeatherBot.h ./Bot.h
    g++ $(FLAGS) -c ./WeatherBot.cpp

Client.o: ./Client.cpp
    g++ $(FLAGS) -c ./Client.cpp


main.o: ./main.cpp 
    g++ $(FLAGS) -c ./main.cpp

Server.o: ./Server.cpp ./Bot.h ./JokerBot.h ./WeatherBot.h ./GrumpyBot.h ./DummyBot.h
    g++ $(FLAGS) -c ./Server.cpp
```

Could anybody please explain me, what causes this error and show me, how to fix it?

Comment: But what exactly shall I post? This problem is accross all the project containig more classes. I don't think that some source code is needed, because as I've said - I'm sure, that the code could be compiled and then run, so the problem is probably in the `Makefile`

Comment: Those are linker errors not compiler errors.

Comment: @chris If those errors wouldn't be caused by linker but the code, don't you think, that it wouldn't compile and run it at all? As I've written in my post - I CAN compile and run the app, when I compile it via `g++ main.cpp -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb -lncurses -pthread -o AppName` . Nevertheless I need to use `Makefile`, thus I can't use this commmand for compilation permanently

Comment: @Dworza, Oh, sorry, I missed that you could link it with one build command. I'll get rid of the space wasting.

Comment: @Dworza , if you get this fixed up ..... do put a word here on what the real thing was ...

Comment: @Dworza , by chance did you have multiple declaration of function in  two or more header files and then included both in the code ?

Comment: Yes, I have the functions that has the same name, but they're doing different stuff and they're in different classes. That is not allowed in `C++` ? O_o

Comment: function overloading is allowed , but it shouldnt cause ambiguity .... the compiler will be able to differentiate based on the signature and arg passed... its a issue if the sig is same and defn different. but Different class should also be a barrier... What going on ?

Comment: No, I think you didn't understand what did I ask. I meant that so, that I have classes `A` and `B`, that `don't inherit` from each other. In class `A` I have `void someFunction()` and I have `void someFunction()` in `B` as well..Can this cause problems?

Comment: Do you by any chance have a `#include "x.cpp"` for any value of `x` in any of your source files?  If so, you're including the wrong file—you need to `#include "x.h"` (the header file) instead.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Look at what the error messages are telling you. Start with the first lines:

```
Server.o: In function `Bot::getRandomMessage()':
/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/./Bot.cpp:18: multiple definition of `Bot::getRandomMessage()'
```

This message says that the object file `Server.o` contains a multiple definition of the function `Bot::getRandomMessage()` function, and that the multiple definition comes from line 18 in the source file `Bot.cpp`. Now look at the next line:

`Bot.o:/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/./Bot.cpp:18: first defined here`

This tells you that the definition in `Server.o` is a multiple definition because there is also a definition in `Bot.o`. It also tells you the definition in `Bot.o` came from line 18 in the source file `Bot.cpp`, which is the same place in the source as the other definition.

**This means that `Bot.cpp` was compiled at least twice, once to make `Server.o` and once to make `Bot.o`.**

That is probably not what you want. It suggests that some of your source or header files include `Bot.cpp` when you meant to include `Bot.h`, or that you have otherwise included `Bot.cpp` incorrectly. Another possibility is that you have a compile command that compiles `Bot.cpp` to make `Server.o`.

Comment: I include everywhere `*.cpp` files, so that might be the problem. If I iclude there `*.h` classes, it keeps me getting errors like `/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/Server.cpp:186: undefined reference to `Bot::getRandomMessage()'
/home/ubuntu/NetBeansProjects/SemestralniPraceChat/Server.cpp:186: undefined reference to `Bot::getName()'`  Because of that, I've thought, that I have to include `*.cpp` ~~> becuase Bot.h defines only the interface and in `Bot.cpp` I include `Bot.h` and implement all the functions...that's how I was thinking.. Isn't it correct?

Comment: @Dworza: You have structured the source files and the build of the project incorrectly. Generally, source files should only include header files to declare things; they should not include other source files to define things. You use linking to provide definitions: Each source file is compiled to an object module, and then the necessary object modules are linked together to provide one executable program.

Answer (score 1):

generally when i face something like this ...... its a double rule occurrence or the project environment is messed up but Bro , this ain't a makefile issue.

you will have to look into the code ..... I simulated and tested the makefile you put in the question here , with empty files and echo . The makefile seems to be working a-ok.

```
  Kaizen ~/so_test $ make -nf mk.t2
  make compile

  Kaizen ~/so_test $ make -nf mk.t2 compile
   echo g++ -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb -pthread -lncurses -g -c ./main.cpp
   echo g++ -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb -pthread -lncurses -g -c ./Bot.cpp
   echo g++ -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb -pthread -lncurses -g -c ./Server.cpp
   echo g++ -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb -pthread -lncurses -g -c ./Client.cpp
   echo g++ -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb -pthread -lncurses -g -c ./GrumpyBot.cpp
   echo g++ -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb -pthread -lncurses -g -c ./JokerBot.cpp
   echo g++ -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb -pthread -lncurses -g -c ./WeatherBot.cpp
   echo g++ -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb -pthread -lncurses -g -c ./DummyBot.cpp
```

i cant deduce much of a suggestion based on whats there , srry ...

Comment: Can you explain, what do you mean with "double rule occurrence" ?

Comment: well thats when you have a rule target mentioned twice in a descriptor file .... think of this compile: $(RUN) mentioned at top of the makefile and at the bottom the make utility reads compile: $(OBJECTS) .... so make dosent know which action to do when it needs to build the target compile but then it wont give you function name in error text

Answer (score 1):

When you compile with `g++ main.cpp -Wall -pedantic -Wno-long-long -O0 -ggdb -lncurses -pthread -o AppName` you actually don't include your `Server`, `Client`, `Bot`, `DummyBot` etc. (That you have in your makefile). Thats why you don't see that error.

also If main.cpp compiles without any other files then why do you need these Client, Bot, Server etc .. in your makefile ?

There must be a redefinition somewhere. try to clean and recompile. and then check the functions that its reporting. like `Server.cpp:74`, `Bot.cpp:18`, `Bot::getRandomMessage()`

also surprisingly your main.cpp doesn't call any Server, Bot ... functions. If it calls its supposed to throw linker errors.